# Logback destination configuration from application.yml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback

I'm trying to configure my logback in XML import destination configuration from application.yml.

When I set static destination in XML then everything is fine but if not then I'm getting this exception on startup:

```
Could not invoke method addDestination in class net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender with parameter of type java.lang.String java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
ERROR in net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender[STASH] - No destination was configured. Use <destination> to add one or more destinations to the appender
```

My dependencies:

- spring-boot:  '1.5.4.RELEASE'
- net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:4.9

logback-spring.xml

```
    <springProperty name="LOGBACK_URL" source="logback.destination.url"/>
    <springProperty name="LOGBACK_PORT" source="logback.destination.port"/>
    <appender name="STASH" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
        <destination>${LOGBACK_URL}:${LOGBACK_PORT}</destination>
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">...
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

applicaiton.yml

```
logback:
  destination:
    url: kibana.test
    port: 1234
```

I'm trying to avoid migrating this config to java and hope it's unnecessary. Thanks in advance !

**EDIT**

I've resolved this problem by adding default value which is space in xml configuration like below:

```
<destination>${LOGBACK_URL:- }:${LOGBACK_PORT:- }</destination>
```

Comment: Are you running the ELK stack with docker-compose? I am having some issues here tying something similar to your case (I am using Maven). Nothing is being sent to logstash.

Answer (score 0):

just leaving it here for anyone facing similar issue, in my case, I had to remove the http:// from the url inside destination tag.